# Asp.Net 4 Form Authentication issue

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, forms-authentication

I've a strange issue with a .NET 4.0 website published on IIS6.

It implements the Forms Authentication, and in my Web.Config I've something like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="2880" name="AUTH_TOKEN" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <allow roles="__AUTHUSER__" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

And I've the Default.aspx setted as default document in the website.

If I try to access the `www.site/default.aspx` it redirects me to the `www.site/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx`

And it is fine.

The problem is that if I try to access `www.site/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=` it gave me a 401.2 error page: not authorized.

It's happening that this is a rebuild of an intranet application and many users actually (for some reason) have the `www.site/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=` url saved in the bookmarks... so I need to get it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding asp.net login controls or custom control like textboxes and button and all..

Comment: The login.aspx page is composed by standard asp.net controls, as the default.aspx...

Comment: Can you just post your aspx code here which shows login control..